# JavaScriptでBasic認証を付けたPOSTリクエストを送る

Tags: javascript, html, http

JavaScriptでPOSTリクエストを送りたいです。
サーバ側から要求されたヘッダー情報は以下の通りです。

- Basic認証
- 'Accept'は'application/json'
- 'Content-Type'は'application/json'
- 'Content-Length'は'*'
- bodyとしてJSON形式のemail
  それで、自分のコードです。

  ```
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

  btn.addEventListener( 'click' , function() {

      var clientId = "*自分のID*";
      var clientSecret = "*自分のPW*";
      var data = { email:"*自分のemail*" };

      var authorizationBasic = window.btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret);

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', '*サーバURL*');
      request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
      request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      //request.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', '*');
      request.send(JSON.stringify(data));

      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (request.readyState === 4) {
              alert(request.responseText);
          }
      };

  } );
  ```

HTMLで実行してもMACのターミナルで実行してもうまく行かないんですが、どこが間違っているんでしょうか？
(HTMLで実行したときChromeではヘッダーとしてContent-Lengthを設定することはできないそうで、そこはコメントアウトしています。)

ちなみに、HTMLで実行したら以下のエラーでした。

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404
```

Comment: 「MACのターミナルで実行」というのは `node` で実行されたという事でよろしいですか？ その場合に実行したコードや、出たエラーはどういった物でしたか？ 「HTMLで実行」 というのは、サーバにHTMLファイルを置いてブラウザでアクセスした、という事でよろしいですか？ その場合、そのサーバはPOST先のサーバと同一ですか？

Answer (score 1):

Basic認証は下記URIでリクエスト出来ます。

```
http://user:password@example.com/
```

click イベントハンドラ内で適切なURIを作成し、`XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` の第二引数に指定すれば実装可能だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

動作環境が見えないの間違っていたら申し訳ないです。
エラーから
アプリなどから通信を行う場合、サーバドメインがlocalhostになり　結果、クロスオリジンの通信になって　'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'が必要と通知されていると思います。

BASIC認証を送るには
AJAXリクエストでクレデンシャル（クッキーの送信またはBASIC認証）を必要とする場合は、それを許可するオプション request.withCredentials = true; を付ける必要があると思います。
更に、クロスオリジンの通信を行う時は、setRequestHeader( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest' );などオプションが必要で、　サーバからは、クロスオリジン許可するheaderを（Access-Control-Allow-Originや他にも必要なeader）出力することが必須になります。

気になった事
POST（要請メソッド）の時のContent-Typeは、通常「application/x-www-form-urlencoded」です。
send( 'json_data='+JSON.stringify({test:"1234567890"}) )と送ると、phpのでの例ですが、$_POST['json_data']で受け取れデバッグが楽です。